# Extended Kalman filter with Non-additive noise

Tags: kalman-filter

I have the following problem. I have the following Kalman filter:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
 \boldsymbol{x}_k=\boldsymbol{x}_{k-1} + \boldsymbol{w}_k \\
 \boldsymbol{y}_k=h(\boldsymbol{x}_{k}, \boldsymbol{v}_k)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

where $\boldsymbol{w}_k$ and $\boldsymbol{w}_k$ are the process and observation noises.

I would like to ask you, if $\boldsymbol{v}_k$ enters the observation equation multiplied by some elements of $\boldsymbol{x}_k$, how can I compute the Jacobians

$\boldsymbol{H}_k= \left. \frac{\partial h}{\partial \boldsymbol{x}} \right|_{\hat{\boldsymbol{x}}_{k|k-1}}$

which I need to compute the updated covariance estimate, please? Should I take the expected value of $\boldsymbol{v}_k$ or should I compute it as at $k-1$?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Is $v_k$ correlated with $x_k$?

Comment: No, no. $v_k$ is uncorrelated both from $x_k$ and $w_k$. Thanks a lot

Comment: My idea is something like $y_t=h(x_t) + x_t*w_t$.. Because  $x_t$ is a collection of different parameters, and some of these parameters multiply the error term.